# Sequelize fill field on first update

Tags: javascript, database, sequelize.js

is it possible to fill a database field on the first update request?

For example: 
The Database have the following fields:

```
id: 1
createdAt: 2020-01-01 10:00:10.490 +00:00
updatedAt: 2020-02-12 17:03:14.172 +00:00
firstUpdate: // <--------- set this field on first update or if it is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something in the lines of:

```
const record = await database.get('record');
if(record.createdAt === record.updatedAt) {
   record.firstUpdate = new Date();
   record.save(); 
}
```

Basically check if `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are same since this they will be same after creation. After each update `updatedAt` will be updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But is there a way to check in the update database request to reduce the requests?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you elaborate more?